# Pro Tools save copy still copies cleared regions

Tags: pro-tools, troubleshooting

Ok so this drives me mad.... everytime I finish a project, I clear all the unused regions from my session and then select save copy in to transfer for mixing. But heres the issue, Pro Tools STILL copies across regions I have cleared and are not in my session! This drives me insane. It never happens on a Mac, but ALWAYS happens on PC! I think it might have something to do with the undo queue? The only way around it i've found is to import the tracks into a new session. This is obviously a pain though. Anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are showing Auto-Created Regions in the Regions bin (option-command-K). If these are being hidden, they will not clear and will be considered part of your session.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this for a long time as well as my colleagues (both Mac and PC).  What we do to circumvent it is do a session save, create a new session, import session data from that saved session.  It appears to be the only thing which solves the issue.

My guess is it's a 'clipboard' type issue where it's not getting flushed out - because when you re-open a session and clear unused AGAIN, even more material is deletable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you do this but just thought I'd offer it up as a suggestion just in case, but, when you clear the regions do you also delete them from the drive or just clear them from the session? If you don't delete them from the drive then it just copies the 'audio files' folder over which still contains the files you cleared from the session.

Cheers

Comment: no it doesn't - when you Save A Copy (& copy all audio files) it only copies whats used in the session... I do this every time I export for dub stage, my session will be referencing hundreds of GB of media but I clear unused & Save a Copy and it only copies whats used in the session...

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to have something to do with the undo history. The way round it I've found works is you Select Unused and Clear them from the session. Save the session and close it. Then open it, Select Unused, Clear them, save the session and close it. Repeating that twice usually clears everything unused. The way to check if it has is to select across all tracks, then select All - check if everything in the Region List is now highlighted. Anything not highlighted means its not used on the tracks, so you need to repeat the process.
Note: I never use playlists

Comment: @tim, I can confirm that process - my regions are never completely cleared until after I've closed and reopened my sessions 3-4 times.

Comment: Thanks guys; I still had the problem yesterday after 2 pro tools restarts and a system restart! All the regions cleared from the region bin etc, then hit save copy in, and immediately the first region it copies is the guide track that i removed!! Nightmare. I will persevere with the exact methods you suggest though! 

Answer (score 0):

I usually save a copy of the session file itself (save as) before clearing unused, just in case, in the same session folder, before doing a "Save Copy In."

So I'll remove unused media (from session, not delete), 'save as', then close the current session, then open the 'saved as' session, then do 'save copy in' and for some reason that seems to get everything cleared out.

I think that essentially does the same as Tim is saying as far as closing and reopening the session a few times with 'remove unused regions' thrown in a couple of times as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch but do you use playlists? It could have a copy of the region in it. That would explain the 'unused' regions in your list. Can't explain the difference between PC & Mac..

(Moved my comment to the proper place "Your Answer")

Comment: Hey Arnoud - I never use playlists, so that cant effect things....

Answer (score 0):

Even if Playlists are used in say loop recording or dubbing, you always select the best take/playlist. So clearing out a session of unused regions should clear out alternative playlists.

I use protools 8.0.3 on mac at work and notice unused regions in the region list that are some how connected to used regions or their children and sometimes dont clear out completely but since they arent very big in size, they can be allowed to remain.

Try upgrading your version to the latest update.